# Cassandra-cli returning more than 100 results

Tags: cassandra

Is there a way to get the cassandra-cli tool to return more than 100 results?

Comment: You might want to hit the http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/IRC IRC channel for an immediate answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes:

```
[default@unknown] help get;
get <cf>['<key>'];
get <cf>['<key>']['<col>'] (as <type>)*;
get <cf>['<key>']['<super>'];
get <cf>['<key>'][<function>];
get <cf>['<key>'][<function>(<super>)][<function>(<col>)];
get <cf> where <column> = <value> [and <column> > <value> and ...] [limit <integer>];
Default LIMIT is 100. Available operations: =, >, >=, <, <=
...

default@unknown] help list;
list <cf>;
list <cf>[<startKey>:];
list <cf>[<startKey>:<endKey>];
list ... limit N;
List a range of rows in the column or supercolumn family.

example:
list Users[j:] limit 40;
```